# How to use nginx "root" and "location" on windows?

Tags: nginx

Here is the conf:

```
location /Desktop/ {
    root   c:/Users/elqstux/;
}
```

the file path is `C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\wy.html`.

when i access `http://127.0.0.1/Desktop/wy.html` in browser, i got `404 Not Found`.

who can tell what's wrong?

Comment: Have you looked around? on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/49414/how-do-i-specify-windows-file-paths-in-nginx) (where your question belong) or in the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)... and maybe check the error logs to have detailed informations?

Comment: check the logfiles, maybe location /Desktop/ should be /Desktop

Answer (score 15):

Use double back slashes to avoid certain character issues (\r is a carriage return.):

```
root C:\\Users\\elelqstux;
```

Comment: failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified) - Your method didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Below 2 configurations working fine on my Windows PC - Nginx-1.23.1

You can try any of these.

// 1

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   "D:\Mamun\github-projects";
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

// 2

```
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /appName {
        root   D://Mamun/github-projects;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Where **appName** is the application folder inside **github-projects** folder.

Access URL

```
http://localhost:8080/appName
http://localhost:8081/appName
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb that worked example could help you.

```
ssl_certificate "C:/Program Files/nginx/ssl/ssl.pem";
ssl_certificate_key "C:/Program Files/nginx/ssl/private.key";
```