# Windows Nginx i can't change the root

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am new to Nginx i started a crash course and i am following the steps but i am stuck at this part and i couldn't find any resources to help me.

```
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        root C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test;
    }
}

events {}
```

Before editing the nginx.conf file everything is fine i can connect to localhost and see nginx welcome html page, but when i delete the configurations i can't connect to it, i tried localhost:8080 too.

Comment: Why you want to delete configuration and for nginx to work as with configuration?

Comment: The `root` directive sets the root **directory**.

Comment: @Justinas course was doing it like this and it worked fine for them

Comment: may be this link help you , https://stackoverflow.com/a/73751109/9854260